# Unable to save MariaDB connection through SQLTools VS code extension

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, mariadb, sqltools

I got an error trying to save myself a connection to MariaDB database using VS Code SQLTools extension on Mac. I can't get rid of the error:

> Unable to save „/.vscode/settings.json” (Unknown (FileSystemError):
>
> Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/.vscode')

I've tried variety of things, ending on complete uninstall of VS, including all of its files and extensions etc. Could someone help me how to deal with this error?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory - the file system where it is trying to create configuration files (for saving your data) is read-only. I suggest you re-install everything paying very close attention to the installation instructions. That path looks completely butchered which adds to the mystery ... but since you need to reinstall anyway you might as well start there. With a good installation, I see no reason why VSCode would want to save things in crazy locations like that.